# I need to know what is the control flow and what exactly is happening in this code?

Tags: java, inheritance

I wrote this code:

```
class A {
    int a;

    void method() {
        System.out.println("Overridden method of Class A called!");
    }

    void method2() {
        System.out.println("Normal Method of Class A called!");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    int b;

    void method() {
        System.out.println("Overridden method of Class B called!");
    }

    void method1() {
        System.out.println("Normal Method of Class B called!");
    }
}

class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a1 = new A();
        B b1 = new B();
        a1 = b1; // ***Line 1***
        System.out.println("After referencing!");
        a1.method();
        a1.method2();

        A a2 = new B(); // ***Line 2***
        a2.method();
        a2.method2();
    }
}
```

***Line 1 and Line 2 are in the code above marked by comments***

Now, I have some idea about the physical significance of ***Line 1***, but what exactly does ***Line 2*** mean?
How is memory being allocated to object '***a2***' of Type A? What is the nature and behaviour of such object and how does it differ from normal instantiation? Does ***Line 1*** and ***Line 2*** convey same meaning? If so, how? If not, how are they different because apparently they give same output.

Comment: The first thing to watch for is terminology. `a2` isn't an object, it's a variable. Its value is a reference. The reference refers to an object of type `B`... but that reference is assignable to a variable of type `A`. Once you've got the terminology sorted, a lot of the rest will make more sense.

Comment: I know that here a2 is just a variable and holds reference to an object in the memory heap, but if you could just please elaborate a bit.

Comment: Here's a tutorial about how values and references work in Java: http://www.javaranch.com/campfire/StoryCups.jsp

Comment: @Ozil check below post for the heap memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always try to code to an interface than to the concrete implementation unless the cases where you find it appropriate (like say classes from Swing, where UI components have concrete implementation but you can override it to get better UI or UI of your choice).

Now considering your case, if I was doing this inheritence just for different behaviours ie different method implementations, i would have preferred an interface 'I' which is implemented by both class A and B. And thats where it starts making more sense.

Above explains the design perspective.

Now from coding perspective. A super class an always reference a subclass object. But when you access a method, its the method of the object which is called but the method of reference type.

```
A a1 = new A();//Object of A in heap which is referred by reference of A
        B b1 = new B();//Object of B in heap which is referred by reference of B
        a1 = b1; // ***Line 1*** Here super type(a1) is referring to subtype b1. So actual object is that of class B.
        System.out.println("After referencing!");
        a1.method();//method from actual object is called ie b1
        a1.method2();//same

        A a2 = new B(); // ***Line 2*** again object created in heap is of type B but its referred by super type A
        a2.method();//and hence,method called is from B class not from class A
        a2.method2();
```

Answer (score 1):

They are the same. In Java all object references maintain the same amount of memory. So the same Object reference's memory space can point to any Java Object. The compiler enforces that you only assign a reference `A` to point to an Object that is of a class that extends `A`. In both the above cases you have a reference (pointer in C) of type `A` that is being pointed to an instance of class `B`.

Comment: So, do Line 1 and Line 2 mean the same thing?

Comment: Almost the same thing. Line 1 assigns a reference to a B object to the variable a1. Line 2 assigns a reference to *another, new* B object to the variable a2. It may be important for a beginner to realize that if B objects are mutable, then changes to a1's object don't affect a2s object (and that changes to a1's object *do* affect b1's object, since a1's object and b1's object are the same object).

Answer (score 1):

a2 is a reference type [of type A] and it is referencing to object of Type B. Thats it, nothing more than that.

Yes Line1 and Line 2 are same thing. Just different ways of doing same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The are both equivalent, but only difference is that in the first you are unnecessarily creating an of `A` (`new A();`) which you just throw away.

```
A a1 = new A(); // new A() should not be done here
B b1 = new B();
a1 = b1; // ***Line 1***
```

It would be better to do it as follows -

```
//A a1 = new A(); // new A() should not be done here
B b1 = new B();
A a1 = b1; // ***Line 1***
```

They are similar because in both cases, you are instantiating an object of `B` (`new B();`), and creating a variable of type `A` to refer to that instance.

Answer (score 1):

Both the lines are just similar to the following

```
Object obj = new SomeClass();
```

But in the Line1 one extra object of type `A` is being created.

So with

```
    A a1 = new A();  // a new object
    B b1 = new B();  // another object
    a1 = b1; // make a1 point to the b1 and lose the reference to original `A` type object

    A a2 = new B(); // create a new `B` object and assign it to reference of `A` type.
```

So essentially the are same (other than the extra object in line1)

**But**

These two lines are internally using the concept of `polymorphism`.